# Angularjs autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a popup in angularjs with a form.I am using a auto-completer as-

```
portfolio.directive('auto', function($timeout) {
    var names = ["john", "bill", "charlie", "robert", "alban", "oscar", "marie", "celine", "brad", "drew", "rebecca", "michel", "francis", "jean", "paul", "pierre", "nicolas", "alfred", "gerard", "louis", "albert", "edouard", "benoit", "guillaume", "nicolas", "joseph"];

    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link : function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.autocomplete({
                source: names,
                onSelect: function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                      iElement.trigger('input');
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
    }
    };
});
```

it is working but the autocomplete box opens behind the popup.
can any one suggest the solution?

Comment: Not enough info to go on here. Can you provide a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)?

Comment: i tried but still the autocomplete box is behind the popup

Comment: can anyone suggest how to add z-index value to the autocomplete box opens on selecting...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/swfjT/894/)**

**Html**

```
<div ng-app='MyModule'>
    <div ng-controller='DefaultCtrl'>
        <input auto  ng-model="selected">
        selected = {{selected}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
function DefaultCtrl($scope) {

}

angular.module('MyModule', []).directive('auto', function($timeout) {
    var names = ["john", "bill", "charlie", "robert", "alban", "oscar", "marie", "celine", "brad", "drew", "rebecca", "michel", "francis", "jean", "paul", "pierre", "nicolas", "alfred", "gerard", "louis", "albert", "edouard", "benoit", "guillaume", "nicolas", "joseph"];

    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link : function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.autocomplete({
                source: names,
                select: function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                      iElement.trigger('input');
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
    }
    };
});
```

Comment: i tried this one that is fine, but tell how to increase the z-index value for the autocomplete popup list

Answer (score 2):

If you require the same with only Angular, then below is an example with pure angular auto-complete.

JS:

```
function DefaultCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["john", "bill", "charlie", "robert", "alban", "oscar", "marie", "celine", "brad", "drew", "rebecca", "michel", "francis", "jean", "paul", "pierre", "nicolas", "alfred", "gerard", "louis", "albert", "edouard", "benoit", "guillaume", "nicolas", "joseph"];
    $scope.showlist = false;
    $scope.clearList = function(){
        $scope.selected = null;
      $scope.showlist = false;
    }

    $scope.selectedItem = function($event, name){
        $scope.selected = name;
      $scope.showlist = false;
    }
}

angular.module('MyModule', []).directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.bind("keypress", function(e){
                    scope.showlist = true;
            })
    };
})
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app='MyModule'>
    <div ng-controller='DefaultCtrl'>
        <input auto-complete ui-items="names" ng-model="selected">
        <button ng-click="clearList()">Clear
        </button>
        <ul ng-show="showlist">
            <li ng-repeat="name in names | filter: selected" ng-click="selectedItem($event, name)">
              {{name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can check fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/swfjT/4601/)

Comment: I had trouble running the fiddle from the answer, so here is a working version with correctly imported dependencies: https://jsfiddle.net/u8fxn9a6/

Answer (score -1):

Use this code to autocomplete:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search for UserName" class="form-control" ng-keydown="checkKeyDown($event)" ng-keyup="checkKeyUp($event)"
```

ng-model="Filters.UserId" ng-change="search()" />
    
    
        {{suggestion}}

Your jQuery Code:

```
//Function To Call On ng-change
$scope.search = function () {
    $scope.searchItems = $rootScope.users;

    //Sort Array       
    $scope.searchItems.sort();
    //Define Suggestions List
    $scope.suggestions = [];
    //Define Selected Suggestion Item
    $scope.selectedIndex = -1;
    $scope.suggestions = [];
    var myMaxSuggestionListLength = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.searchItems.length; i++) {
        var searchItemsSmallLetters = angular.lowercase($scope.searchItems[i].UserID);
        var searchTextSmallLetters = angular.lowercase($scope.Filters.UserId);
        if (searchItemsSmallLetters.indexOf(searchTextSmallLetters) !== -1) {
            $scope.suggestions.push(searchItemsSmallLetters);
            myMaxSuggestionListLength += 1;
            if (myMaxSuggestionListLength == 10) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

//Keep Track Of Search Text Value During The Selection From The Suggestions List  
$scope.$watch('selectedIndex', function (val) {
    if (val !== -1 && val != undefined) {
        $scope.Filters.UserId = $scope.suggestions[$scope.selectedIndex];
    }
});

//Text Field Events
//Function To Call on ng-keydown
$scope.checkKeyDown = function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 40) {//down key, increment selectedIndex
        event.preventDefault();
        if ($scope.selectedIndex + 1 !== $scope.suggestions.length) {
            $scope.selectedIndex++;
        }
    } else if (event.keyCode === 38) { //up key, decrement selectedIndex
        event.preventDefault();
        if ($scope.selectedIndex - 1 !== -1) {
            $scope.selectedIndex--;
        }
    } else if (event.keyCode === 13) { //enter key, empty suggestions array
        event.preventDefault();
        $scope.suggestions = [];
    }
}

//Function To Call on ng-keyup
$scope.checkKeyUp = function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode !== 8 || event.keyCode !== 46) {//delete or backspace
        if ($scope.Filters.UserId == "") {
            $scope.suggestions = [];
        }
    }
}
//======================================

//List Item Events
//Function To Call on ng-click
$scope.AssignValueAndHide = function (index) {
    $scope.Filters.UserId = $scope.suggestions[index];
    $scope.suggestions = [];
}
//======================================
//User Autocomplete end
```